# Conditional strip values left of delimiter pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in a pandas DF that looks like :

```
Column
30482304823
3204820
2304830
Apple   - 390483204
Orange - 3939491
grape - 34038414
apple
```

I want to remove everything to the left of the '-' so basically I want the above to look like :

```
Column
30482304823
3204820
2304830
390483204
3939491
34038414
apple
```

I have tried the following pandas snippets :

```
out['Column'] = out['Column'].str.split('-', 1, expand=True)[1]
out['Column'] = out['Column'].str.replace('Orange -', '', )
out['Column'].str.map(lambda x: x.lstrip('Orange -'))
out['Column'].str.lstrip('Orange -')
```

Comment: Try this:
`out['column'] = out['column'].apply(lambda x : str(x).split('-')[-1])`

Comment: works great thank you!

Comment: Mark it in the answer section!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`out['Column'] = out['Column'].apply(lambda x : str(x).split('-')[-1])`

Answer (score 3):

Simplest I can think of is

```
df.Column.str.split('\s*-\s*').str[-1]

0    30482304823
1        3204820
2        2304830
3      390483204
4        3939491
5       34038414
6          apple
Name: Column, dtype: object
```

Comment: This is very clever!